# matplotlib scatter plot with full year date-time index

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas series with a datetime index and values from the year 2015.
Not all dates have data, so dropna() was employed to look at attained data.
Part of the data is displayed below, there are roughly 50 dates with observations in the 
whole series.

```
  date       value

2015-02-09     8.3
2015-04-17    27.8
2015-05-07    30.6
...
2015-07-27    33.9
2015-07-29    36.1
2015-08-19    32.8
...
2015-12-25    11.1
2015-12-26    11.7
```

How would I create a matplotlib scatter plot out of this data, 
using the full year of 2015 as the range of the x-axis?

Answer (score 1):

Pandas has its own plotting method for this, which is a wrapper for the matplotlib function:

```py
import pandas as pd

<name of your series>.plot(xlim=[pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01'), 
                                 pd.to_datetime('2015-12-31')])
```

This may draw a lineplot by default, which is the conventional way to display time series. But you can use all the usual matplotlib keyword arguments and plotting functions to customize the plot.

---

**Follow-up question:** *How to overlay several plots with the same x limits?*

If the two series you want to plot are the two columns of one DataFrame, you can use the same method as above. Just substitute the DataFrame for the Series.

If the second dataset you want to plot is something else (say (x, y)), you may want to use the more flexible object-oriented matplotlib interface:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots() 

ax.plot(<series>.index, <series>.values)
ax.plot(x, y)

ax.set_xlim([pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01'), 
             pd.to_datetime('2015-12-31')])
```

Comment: this works, but i have a followup question. I need to overlay this data on another graph with the same date range, and i'm struggling to set up the axis parameters. how would u set up the axis to represent the the entire 2015 calendar year and then apply these graphs?

Comment: I added this to my answer.